# Import All - command in python not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, import, project, plotly-dash

I have 3 scripts and I must import one of them to the other two for continuing my project.
It's happening a curious thing, the same command is not working properly, as shown below:

[Trying to check a DataFrame from globals.py script - not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5W4Z.png)

[Trying to check the same DataFrame from globals.py script - working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOjvb.png)

Does anyone know what is happening?
It's the same command for two different scripts, but doesn't work properly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Careful, `globals()` is a potentially important thing in python.

Comment: @JonSG hello Jon !! globals.py is only the name of a script, not the function you're mentioning